# jQuery Validator - errorPlacement - Finding the next td.foo after element

Tags: jquery, validation

I am trying to use jQuery Validator's errorPlacement to append the error message to the next TD.multiError AFTER the offending element.

There are cells with required radio inputs and I would like the message to proceed from element through the table cells until it hits one with class multiError and append the message there.

What is the correct way to do this?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#surveyForm").validate({
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) { 
            if ( element.is(":radio") ) 
                error.appendTo( element.nextAll('td.multiError:first') ); 
            else if ( element.is(":checkbox") ) 
                error.appendTo ( element.next() ); 
            else 
                error.appendTo( element.parent() ); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
<td class='colspan' colspan='2'><p>Which of the following most accurately describes your laboratory facility?&nbsp;</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='two_columns'><label><input type='radio' name='rad_22' id='ans_18' class='required' value='18'  />  Private / Reference Lab</label>
</td>
<td class='two_columns'><label><input type='radio' name='rad_22' id='ans_19' class='required' value='19'  />  Physician's Office</label>
</td>
</tr>
<td class='two_columns'><input type='text' name='ans_23' id='ans_23' value='' class='required' />
</td>
</tr><tr><td colspan='2' class='multiError'></td></tr>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I altered the script so that the TD has an ID concatenating the radio button group name eg "rad_22" and "_multiError".

The appendTo call then became

```
error.appendTo ( eval(element.attr('name') + '_multiError') );
```

This works well but I would still love to have an answer as to how to walk through all DOM elements from a starting element and match on the first .foo.